# Arch Linux - many commands not found

Tags: arch-linux

I just installed Arch Linux on my machine, but many of the commands simply don't work. Those that work are the very basics, such as `cd` and `ls`, but things like `visudo` are not found.

Answer (score 6):

The `visudo` command is provided by the `sudo` package, which is not part of a base install of Arch Linux. If you installed the `base-devel` package group, then you should have it.

The `base` package group contains just slightly more than the minimum possible to get a system running (it does, for example, give you two text editors). Beyond this, you will almost certainly have to install additional packages to make the system meet your needs.

This might be seen as an inconvenience upfront, but it makes for a cleaner system since you don't need to have things installed that you won't use.

In order to determine which package contains a program called `foo`, you can generally use:

```
pacman -Fy # update the database
pacman -Fo /usr/bin/foo
```

You might also find use from

```
pacman -Fs foo
```

This searches for packages that own any file named `foo` rather than just `/usr/bin/foo`. See `pacman(8)` for more details.

Comment: The `-Fo` argument only works with files you have installed. To search for files/program not installed you should use `-Fs` instead. E.g. `pacman -Fs visudo`.

Comment: @Christer That is false. `-Qo` is for installed things. (Just tested on my machine to make sure)

Comment: Ah yes, you are totally right. I confused `-Fo` with `-Qo`. `-Fs` is still a nice alternative when locating a missing program.

Comment: @Christer That I'll agree with. I originally mentioned it, then removed it for simplicity